# if...else condition in React Native

Tags: react-native

i am new to react native. In my application i am stuck with if..else condition in which i am displaying  views based on a condition. Here is the code.

```
if ({ this.state.isSignUp }) {
     <Text> Sign Up </Text>
} else {
     <Text> Forgot Password </Text>
}
```

In my login page i have links for Forgot password and Sign Up pages for which i am showing a Modal page based on isSignUp bool value. I am jus trying to display a text in the Modal page based on the condition, but i am stuck with the below error.[image] Can anyone tell me if i am doing this in the right way. Any help is appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For conditional rendering i would recommend to create a new function. Inside a function you can use if/else like normal. e.g

```
renderConditionalText() {
    if (this.state.isSignUp) {
        return <Text> Sign Up </Text>;
    }
     return <Text> Forgot Password </Text>; 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this.

```
  let text;
  if (this.state.isSignUp) {
       text = <Text> Sign Up </Text>
  } else {
       text = <Text> Forgot Password </Text>
  }
  return text;
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no need to a function in JSX to use conditions.

You can use [Inline If with Logical && Operator](https://reactjs.org/docs/conditional-rendering.html#inline-if-else-with-conditional-operator)

It also called **ternary** operator. For further info please [see](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator)

Example from React Doc;

```
render() {
  const isLoggedIn = this.state.isLoggedIn;
  return (
    <div>
      The user is <b>{isLoggedIn ? 'currently' : 'not'}</b> logged in.
    </div>
  );
}
```

--

It can also be used for larger expressions although it is less obvious what’s going on:

```
render() {
  const isLoggedIn = this.state.isLoggedIn;
  return (
    <div>
      {isLoggedIn ? (
        <LogoutButton onClick={this.handleLogoutClick} />
      ) : (
        <LoginButton onClick={this.handleLoginClick} />
      )}
    </div>
  );
}
```